Embed HTML Application in Dash application
I have created a multi-page dash application using dash which contains lots of table and graph/charts and I have also created a html hosted application which drive the purpose of showing mapbox gl, plotting marker points on it , selecting marker using inbulti EditDraw function and perform other spatial analysis using turf.js. How can I embed this html application in one of the tabs in dash application? Basically, I want to select marker point saves them in database (which I can do it using flask) and pick that database in dash datatable/dataframe for further calculation and populate dash datatable using dash components like dropdown etc.
or if this is not possible then how can I do the reverse process to embed dash application tabs in nav-bar of html layout webpage where each link in nav-bar of can be used to redirect the dash pages application and use html components to render dash graph/charts?
Even If I use Iframe to embed Dash application in html webpage is it possible to render graph/charts using buttons/dropdown etc which is not a part of App.layout ?
[My HTML application script code is :] (https://i.sstatic.net/WxEMJuWw.png)
I tried using embedding the dash page in html web page using flask, but I am facing two problems

If I click on dash page linked in nav-bar it open new page instead of showing in same html webpage layout.
I don't understand how to render dash plotly graph/charts using the dropdown which is built in html and not inside app.layout


Don't share your code as an Image, provide it directly so other could help.
